# Print all the "specific" strings in a txt file using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file which has 2 main types of string (the date and some info), which looks a little like this:

```
29.04.16_09.35
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.4.3
websockets==1.0.0

04.05.16_15.01
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.8.0
websockets==1.0.1

#... and several more of those blocks^
```

I'm trying to write a script which prints out all the dates (with a day.month.year_hour.minute format). I tried something along the lines of...

```
disp_x=`cat myfile.txt | grep "??.??.??_??.??"`
echo "$disp_x"
```

but it outputs nothing. The ? is a metacharacter so technically it should work right?

Comment: `awk '/^[[:digit:]]/' file`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` does not use globs; it uses *regular expressions*.  Consequently, try something like:

```
$ disp_x=$(grep '..\...\..._..\...' myfile.txt)
$ echo "$disp_x"
29.04.16_09.35
04.05.16_15.01
```

In a glob, `?` means any character.  By contrast, in regular expressions, `?` means zero or move of the preceeding character.  To get any character in a regex, use `.`.  To get a literal period in regex, escape it: `\.`.

Or, to require numbers:

```
$ disp_x=$(grep -E '[[:digit:].]{8}_[[:digit:].]{5}' myfile.txt)
$ echo "$disp_x"
29.04.16_09.35
04.05.16_15.01
```

`[:digit:]` matches any digit.  Unlike `[0-9]`, it is unicode-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can `grep` the file using a regular expression :

```
grep -xE '([0-9]{2}[._]*)*' filename
```

`[0-9]{2}` to match two digits, `[._]*` to match these characters occurring any times and the whole expression in parentheses + `*` to match the whole thing any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `egrep` also

```
egrep '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]' filename
```

In script

```
#!/bin/bash
disp_x=$(egrep '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]' filename)
echo "$disp_x"
```